# Why in View result tree, URL is displaying with plus sign and after expending it, It is displaying like 'URL'-0 and 'URL'-1

Tags: jmeter

Why in View result tree, URL is displaying with plus sign and after expending it, It is displaying like 'URL'-0 and 'URL'-1

[image]

HTTP Request:

```
Method : POST
Path: /WebForms/Patient/HomeMedsDU.aspx?Mode=view
Content Encoding: utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a new behaviour since [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5/), see [Bug 62550 - Modify SubResult Naming Policy for more details](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62550)

If you're running JMeter from GUI with low number of virtual users you can tick `Functional Test Mode` box on [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level

[image]

If you're [running JMeter tests in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and storing request and response data causes massive disk IO and you want to avoid it and/or this SubResult Naming Policy causes problems you can get the previous behaviour back by adding the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation:

```
subresults.disable_renaming=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.